# Reading and formatting Access data

Tags: javascript, html, database, ms-access, hta

I'm using JavaScript and HTA to read data in access database (.mdb) on local but having a small issue. My JavaScript code is like this:

```
function miseryBusiness() {
    var box = document.getElementById("lyrics");
    box.innerHTML = "";

    var db = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='paramore.mdb'";
    var adoConn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    var adoRS = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
    adoConn.Open(db);
    adoRS.Open("SELECT * from 2007_RIOT WHERE track=4", adoConn, 1, 3);

    var lyrics = adoRS.Fields("lyrics").value;
    box.innerText = lyrics;

    adoRS.Close();
    adoConn.Close();
}
```

I have a div in the page with id="lyrics". Function gets the specified cell's value and change's div's inner text to that value.

What I want to do is use innerHTML instead of innerText. And if I use inner HTML I get the cell's value as a single line. I want to add line breaks to the end of the each line. Also an anchor to the beginning of the text.

If I was getting the text from a .txt file I'd use

```
while(!lyrics.AtEndOfStream) {
    box.innerHTML += '<a id="miseryBusiness">' + lyrics.ReadLine() + '<br/>';
}
```

but this doesn't work with access database. Or I couldn't get it to work. Any ideas?

The HTA and .mdb file I'm using: [link1](http://dfiles.eu/files/6jd8963rh) [link2](http://www.speedyshare.com/asgKG/db.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lyrics are in a Memo field with hard line-breaks then the line terminator is almost certainly `<cr><lf>`, so try the following:

```
box.innerHTML = '<a id="miseryBusiness">' + lyrics.replace(/\r\n/g, '<br/>');
```

Comment: @akinuri Sorry, I guess I misunderstood your issue. Is it that you can retrieve the text from the .mdb file but the formatting is not to your liking?

Comment: Exactly. I can get the text and change div's content with innerText but I want to use innerHTML to add an anchor and line breaks to the text.